# How to identify the internet status of the computer using Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

So that we can identify the status and proceed accordingly. Otherwise we have to face unwanted errors

Answer (score 4):

**SHORT ANSWER**
By using the provided Utility - Network object's *Ping* action to run three ping tests for analysis.

**CORRECT ANSWER**
By using the provided Utility - Network object's *Ping* action to run three ping tests for analysis **BUT** this **wholly** depends on the network setup of your resource PC.
As well if you have any kind of Firewall configured to block ICMP packets a result will be that you can not send ICMP echo request packets to external networks.

However, let's say you know your network architecture enough to be certain the resource PC can directly send and receive packets. If that were the case then Solution 1 will work.
IF your resource is well and rightly insulated within your organizations network BUT are confident that your network exit points are always connected to the internet AND know your domain network name or IP Solution 2 will work.

**Solution 1**
`ping google.com`
To test that DNS is working on the resource 
`ping 8.8.8.8`
 To test that resource's TCP/IP settings are correct
`ping 127.0.0.1`
 Loopback test to make sure there's nothing wrong with the resource's network adapter or connection settings

Depending on your requirements you can also directly ping the endpoint addresses your bot needs to communicate with. This would be especially useful if the bot is not using a browser-based application, but rather sending emails.

**Solution 2**
`ping {yourdomainnetwork}.com`
To test that DNS is working on the resource 
`ping {yourdomainnetwork IP}`
 To test that resource's TCP/IP settings are correct
`ping 127.0.0.1`
 Loopback test to make sure there's nothing wrong with the resource's network adapter or connection settings

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - this is a correct (and frankly, probably the best) answer.

Comment: @esqew thanks, appreciate it. I think because it's a poor question and I made some assumptions by answering it.

Comment: @esqew You get used to it, some people just do it.